# Updating the FAQs and community information

Tags: discussion, feature-request

As we grow and evolve our understanding as a community, it's time to update the [FAQs and other site information](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help). Some suggestions from members so far include:

- [What is the definition of open data](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/would-it-be-possible-to-get-an-explanation-of-what-open-data-is-added-to-the-faq)?
- [How should users note appropriate affiliations](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59/how-should-we-handle-affiliation-disclosure)?

What other topics would you like to see addressed or modified?

Comment: Have these questions included in the FAQ? Because I cannot find them.

Answer (score 2):

### What is on-topic?

We've had various comments to close questions that some members of the community felt weren't on-topic.  I don't think that we can rely on classifical categorization, so it might be worth trying to tease out where the boundaries might be:

- is free but not open data acceptable?
- how 'open' does the data have to be?
- do tools have to be 'open' as well as the data?
- where do we draw the line between using the data vs. programming (and thus on StackOverflow)?

We had something [similar on dba.SE](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11/51), due to the strange origins of that site.